# Adding a class to a specific element on click with Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using meteor.js and I am trying to add a class to specific button elements on click.

I am getting the correct id for the elements with event.currentTarget.id, but the class I am adding is not being added (.selected).  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you!

```
Template.inquiry.events({
    'click .button': function(event){
        console.log(event.currentTarget.id)

        var report=event.currentTarget.id

        $(report).addClass('selected');

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery expects a string such as `#my-item` when looking up by id.

You probably need to do:

```
$("#" + report).addClass("selected");
```